# Filtering number of results in swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm busy making an app that generates random movie results in swiftUI. Right now the default is 3 but I want to be able to change that varying from 1 tot 10. So if a user wants 5 results instead of 3 it should override the default to 5. Unfortunately I can't figure it out. can anyone help me?

This is the filterView

```
 let optionRange = 1...10
    @State var numOptions: Int = 3

var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    VStack {
                        Picker("Nr. of options", selection: $numOptions) {
                            ForEach(optionRange, id: \.self) { option in
                                Text("\(option)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
}
                Button(action: {
                    let randomiserView = RandomiserView(numOptions: numOptions)
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Done")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width:300, height: 50)
                        .background(Color.accentColor)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                })
            }
            .navigationTitle("Filter")
        }
    }
}
```

This is the randomiserView

```
@State var numOptions: Int = 3
@State var randomNumber = [Int]()

var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                    .frame(height: 10)
                Button("Filters") {
                    isShowingFilters.toggle()
                }
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .frame(width:300, height: 50)
                .background(Color.accentColor)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingFilters) {
                    FilterView(numOptions: numOptions)
                }

                Spacer()
                
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 30) {
                        Spacer()
                        ForEach(filteredMovies, id: \.self) { movie in
                            NavigationLink(destination: MovieDetailView(movieId: movie.id)) {
                                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                    HStack{
//                                        Text("\(numOptions / numOptions)")
                                        Text(movie.title)
                                            .font(
                                                .system(size: 25)
                                                .weight(.bold)
                                            )
                                            .foregroundColor(CustomColor.textColor)
                                    }
                                    MoviePosterCard(movie: movie)
                                        .frame(width: 260, height: 390)
                                    Text(movie.genreText)
                                        .foregroundColor(CustomColor.textColor)
                                    HStack {
                                        Image("Heart")
                                            .resizable()
                                            .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                                            .padding(.trailing, -5)
                                        Text(movie.ratingText).foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                                    }
                                    .padding(.top, -10)
                                    .padding(.bottom, -10)
                                }
                                .frame(width: 260)
                                .padding(20)
                                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                            }
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }

                Spacer()

                Button(action: {
                    var randomNumbers = [Int]()
                    while randomNumbers.count < numOptions {
                        let randomNumber = Int.random(in: 1...1000)
                        randomNumbers.append(randomNumber)
                        print(randomNumber)
                    }

                    var fetchedRandomMovies = [Movie]()

                    for randomNumbers in randomNumber {
                        MovieStore.shared.fetchMovies(from: .popular) { result in
                            switch result {
                            case .success(let movies):
                                fetchedRandomMovies.append(movie)
                            case .failure(let error):
                                print(error.localizedDescription)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    var fetchedMovies = [Movie]()
                    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

                    for id in randomNumbers {
                        dispatchGroup.enter()
                        MovieStore.shared.fetchMovie(id: id) { result in
                            switch result {
                            case .success(let movie):
                                fetchedMovies.append(movie)
                            case .failure(let error):
                                print(error.localizedDescription)
                            }
                            dispatchGroup.leave()
                        }
                    }

                    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
                        self.filteredMovies = fetchedMovies
                        self.movieTitles = fetchedMovies.map({ $0.title })
                        print(self.movieTitles)
                    }
                    
                }) {
                    Text("Randomise")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width:300, height: 50)
                        .background(Color.accentColor)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
```

Right now the 'done' button in the filterview does absolutely nothing. When I select some filters and press done, the filters are not preserved.

Answer (score 0):

In your filter view you need to change the `numOptions` to be a `Binding` since you want the change to the property to affect the corresponding property in the `RandomiserView`

```
@Binding var numOptions: Int
```

Then in the `Button` action you should only dismiss the view

```
Button(action: {
    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
}, label: { 
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I changed it to a binding and set a default of 3 in the picker. but the value still does not change

Comment: No need to set it to a default value, you already do that in the RandomiserView

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you are not injecting the `numOptions` variable from `filterView` into `randomiserView`; `radomiserView` is using the variable `named(numOptions)` from its own. Try to use the initializer to inject this variable from the filter to the randomiser, or use binding for `numOptions` inside of `randomiserView`.

Comment: I believe I linked it now, but the value does not change. Filterview: @Binding var numOptions: Int?
                    VStack {
                        Picker("Nr. of options", selection: $numOptions) {
                            ForEach(optionRange, id: \.self) { option in
                                Text("\(option)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .onAppear {
                        if numOptions == nil {
                            numOptions = 3
                        }
                    }

Comment: @JoostvanGrieken You should read up on State and Binding so you understand what they are and how they are used together